# Sidebar not displaying on custom-page.php

Tags: sidebar, page-template

Ok, I registered a new sidebar and have added some functionality to my theme so you can choose which sidebar to display from the back-end (using meta fields). It's working on all pages, except on a custom-page.php I created.

I've tried just about anything and can't get my head around why my selected sidebar isn't displaying on page.php (default sidebar is displaying), but not on custom-page.php. I might be overlooking something minor, but for now it's doing my head in. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. I forgot to add
    wp_reset_query();
which should always be added when using custom queries.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the following line in your custom-page.php:

```
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
```

?

Comment: I can call it directly
    `<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'gear-sidebar' ); ?>`
which will display the correct sidebar next to the old one. Don't know why the "dynamic part" of calling it isn't working on this custom page, while it is on the regular pages.